# Wrong distribution from inverse(CDF) transform sampling

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy

I am trying to simulate a geometric distribution, using the Inverse CDF method, however I am getting slightly wrong results and I am not sure why.

To be more specific, a geometric distribution with a shape factor p = 0.8, should have the following characteristics:

```
mean: 1.25 
variance: 0.31
```

However, running the code below, I am getting:

```
mean: 0.6224363901913519
var: 0.391813011265263
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

As you can see, I am getting a wildly different mean value compared to the expected one.

> np.log(uniform[i])/np.log(1-p) is the result of solving the equation:
>   F(X) = R for X in terms of R, F(X) = CDF of geometric distribution = 1 - (1 - p)^k.

R is a uniform distribution over the interval (0,1).

So solving it results in the following:

> X = ln(1-R)/ln(1-p)

However, since both 1-R and R are uniformly distributed on (0,1), we can do the following simplification:

> X = ln(R)/ln(1-p)

The above equation is correct and should result in a geometric distribution sample.

```
import numpy as np

n = 10000
p = 0.8
geo_dist = np.zeros(n,dtype = np.float64)
uniform = np.random.uniform(0, 1, n)
for i in range(n):
    geo_dist[i] = np.log(uniform[i])/np.log(1-p)
print("mean: " +str(geo_dist.mean()))
print("var: " +str(geo_dist.var()))
```

I have tried increasing the calculation precision by using np.float64 in a desperate attempt to fix what should be a trivial script, to no avail.

I have also tried generating the uniform distribution using scipy uniform.rvs() instead of np.uniform and the problem persists.

If p = 0.5:

```
expected mean: 2
expected variance : 2
```

However, the code I have written has the following result:

```
mean: 1.4440009653569306
var: 2.0421079966161093
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Anybody have any idea why this is not working?
Thank you.

Comment: Could the problem be that the geometric distribution is a discrete distribution but this samples from a continuation of the discrete distribution (and therefore does not produce whole numbers)?

Comment: Yeah, apparently I had to use math.ceil() and my quantile function is now correct. Thank you for pointing me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually sampling continuous [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) with lambda being equal to -1/ln(1-p)

Ok, here is the code with the right sampling, ceiling is applied to exponential output

```
import numpy as np

N = 100000
p = 0.8

q = np.random.random(N)
g = np.ceil(np.log(1.0 - q)/np.log(1.0-p))

print(np.mean(g))
print(np.var(g))
```

which prints

```
1.25055
0.3146946975
```

Please, note that:

1. You'd better use NumPy vectorizing capabilities without explicit loops
2. Replacement `(1-R) -> R` for `R` being sampled from U(0,1) doesn't work for NumPy RNG - it returns values in semi-closed range [0...1), which means you could get log(0) and FP exception from time to time.

Comment: But according to [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/distributions-geometric-quantile) , my quantile function is correct. So my method is incorrect?

Comment: Actually, just noticed, if I use math.ceil(), my quantile function has the correct results. So apparently I may have implemented the function wrong, so now I get better results.

Comment: @Michail Yes, you lost ceiling function somewhere in translation. Please take a look at update, it has code and few points I would like to make.

Comment: Thank you very much! As for the numpy vectorizing capabilities, I was not aware about them, thank you for teaching me something new!